# Drupal Quick Integration Soap Mapping Callback empty

Tags: php, drupal, quickbooks

I am trying to create a custom module which sync the order data from drupal to my quick books enterprice edition through the quickbooks webconnector.

I am following https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/tree/master/docs/web_connector link

As Suggested in above github repository i have created a QWC File.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<QBWCXML>
<AppName>The Reconnection Test</AppName>
<AppID></AppID>
<AppURL>http://localhost/reconnection/quickbooks/server</AppURL>
<AppDescription>test</AppDescription>
<AppSupport>http://localhost/reconnection/quickbooks/server</AppSupport>
<UserName>admin</UserName>
<OwnerID>{55ab00a1-961c-b214-79da-e5342f57001d}</OwnerID>
<FileID>{0eb834fe-721d-ed34-e13c-fb81ba65d564}</FileID>
<QBType>QBFS</QBType>
<Notify>false</Notify>
<Scheduler>
<RunEveryNMinutes>10</RunEveryNMinutes>
</Scheduler>
<IsReadOnly>false</IsReadOnly>
</QBWCXML>
```

And A soap end point

```
function reconnection_quickbooks_server() 
{
// A username and password you'll use in: 
//  a) Your .QWC file
//  b) The Web Connector
//  c) The QuickBooks framework
//
//  NOTE: This has *no relationship* with QuickBooks usernames, Windows 
usernames, etc. 
//      It is *only* used for the Web Connector and SOAP server! 
$data = _quickbooks_config();
$user = $data['username'];
$pass = $data['password'];
$errmap = array();
// Map QuickBooks actions to handler functions
$map = array(
QUICKBOOKS_ADD_CUSTOMER => array( '_quickbooks_customer_add_request', 
'_quickbooks_customer_add_response' ),
QUICKBOOKS_ADD_SALESRECEIPT => array('_quickbooks_salesreceipt_add_request','_quickbooks_salesreceipt_add_response')
);

$errmap = array();
// An array of callback hooks
$hooks = array(
// There are many hooks defined which allow you to run your own 
functions/methods when certain events happen within the framework
QuickBooks_WebConnector_Handlers::HOOK_LOGINSUCCESS => 
'_quickbooks_hook_loginsuccess',    // Run this function whenever a 
 successful login occurs
);
// Logging level
//$log_level = QUICKBOOKS_LOG_NORMAL;
//$log_level = QUICKBOOKS_LOG_VERBOSE;
//$log_level = QUICKBOOKS_LOG_DEBUG;                
$log_level = QUICKBOOKS_LOG_DEVELOP;        // Use this level until you're 
sure everything works!!!
// What SOAP server you're using 
$soapserver = QUICKBOOKS_SOAPSERVER_PHP;            // The PHP SOAP 
extension, see: www.php.net/soap
//$soapserver = QUICKBOOKS_SOAPSERVER_BUILTIN;      // A pure-PHP SOAP 
server (no PHP ext/soap extension required, also makes debugging easier)

$soap_options = array(      // See http://www.php.net/soap);

$handler_options = array(
//'authenticate_dsn' => 'function://your_function_name_here', 
'deny_concurrent_logins' => false, 
);      // See the comments in the QuickBooks/Server/Handlers.php file

$driver_options = array(        // See the comments in the QuickBooks/Driver/<YOUR DRIVER HERE>.php file ( i.e. 'Mysql.php', etc. )
'max_log_history' => 32000, // Limit the number of quickbooks_log entries to 1024
'max_queue_history' => 1024,    // Limit the number of *successfully processed* quickbooks_queue entries to 64
);

$callback_options = array(
);

// DSN connection string
$dsn = _quickbooks_dsn();
$orders = commerce_order_load(79);

if (!QuickBooks_Utilities::initialized($dsn))
{
// Initialize creates the neccessary database schema for queueing up requests and logging
QuickBooks_Utilities::initialize($dsn);

// This creates a username and password which is used by the Web Connector to authenticate
QuickBooks_Utilities::createUser($dsn, $user, $pass);
}
QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue_Singleton::initialize($dsn);
$Queue = new QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue($dsn);
$Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_ADD_CUSTOMER, $orders->order_number);
$Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_ADD_SALESRECEIPT, $orders->order_number);



// Create a new server and tell it to handle the requests
// __construct($dsn_or_conn, $map, $errmap = array(), $hooks = array(), $log_level = QUICKBOOKS_LOG_NORMAL, $soap = QUICKBOOKS_SOAPSERVER_PHP, $wsdl = QUICKBOOKS_WSDL, $soap_options = array(), $handler_options = array(), $driver_options = array(), $callback_options = array()
$Server = new QuickBooks_WebConnector_Server($dsn, $map, $errmap, $hooks, $log_level, $soapserver, QUICKBOOKS_WSDL, $soap_options, $handler_options, $driver_options, $callback_options);
$response = $Server->handle(true, true);
}
```

mapping callback functions

```
function _quickbooks_customer_add_request($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale)
{

$id = (int) $ID;
    $order = commerce_order_load($id);

    $drupal_user_id = (int) $order->uid;
    $drupal_user = user_load($drupal_user_id);

    $billing_profile = commerce_customer_profile_load($order->commerce_customer_billing['und'][0]['profile_id']);
    $registration_profile = commerce_customer_profile_load($order->commerce_customer_rc_register['und'][0]['profile_id']);
    $billing_address = $billing_profile->commerce_customer_address['und'][0];
$country_list = _addressfield_country_options_list();
$country_name = $country_list[$billing_address['country']];

    $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <?qbxml version="13.0"?>
        <QBXML>
            <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
                <CustomerAddRq>
                    <CustomerAdd>
                        <Name>'.$drupal_user->field_first_name['und'][0]['value']. ' '.$drupal_user->field_last_name['und'][0]['value'].'</Name>';


                        if(isset($drupal_user->field_business_name) && !empty($drupal_user->field_business_name)){
                       $xml .= '<CompanyName>'.$drupal_user->field_business_name['und'][0]['value'].'</CompanyName>';
                        }
                        if(isset($drupal_user->field_first_name) && !empty($drupal_user->field_first_name)){
                        $xml .= '<FirstName>'.$drupal_user->field_first_name['und'][0]['value'].'</FirstName>';
                        }
                        if(isset($drupal_user->field_last_name) && !empty($drupal_user->field_last_name)){
                         $xml .='<LastName>'.$drupal_user->field_last_name['und'][0]['value'].'</LastName>';
                        }

                        $xml .= '<BillAddress>';
                        if(isset($billing_address['thoroughfare']) && !empty($billing_address['thoroughfare'])){

                            $xml .= '<Addr1>'.$billing_address['thoroughfare'].'</Addr1>';
                        }
                        if(isset($billing_address['premise']) && !empty($billing_address['premise'])){
                            '<Addr2>'.$billing_address['premise'].'</Addr2>';
                        }
                         if(isset($billing_address['locality']) && !empty($billing_address['locality'])){
                           $xml .=   '<City>'.$billing_address['locality'].'</City>';
                       }
                        if(isset($billing_address['administrative_area']) && !empty($billing_address['administrative_area'])){
                            $xml .=  '<State>'.$billing_address['administrative_area'].'</State>';
                        }
                        if(isset($billing_address['postal_code']) && !empty($billing_address['postal_code'])){
                            $xml .=  '<PostalCode>'.$billing_address['postal_code'].'</PostalCode>';
                        }
                       if(isset($billing_address['country_name']) && !empty($billing_address['country_name'])){
                           $xml .=   '<Country>'.$country_name.'</Country>';
                       }
                         $xml .=   '</BillAddress>';
                         if(isset($drupal_user->field_phone_number) && !empty($drupal_user->field_phone_number)){

                         $xml .=   '<Phone>'.$drupal_user->field_phone_number['und'][0]['value'].'</Phone>';
                         }

                        //$xml .=    '<AltPhone>860-429-0021</AltPhone>';
                          //$xml .=  '<Fax>860-429-5183</Fax>';

                            $xml .=  '<Email>'.$drupal_user->mail.'</Email>';
                          $xml .=  '<Contact>'.$drupal_user->field_first_name['und'][0]['value']. ' '.$drupal_user->field_last_name['und'][0]['value']. 
                          '</Contact>';
                   $xml .= '</CustomerAdd>
                </CustomerAddRq>
            </QBXMLMsgsRq>
        </QBXML>';


    return $xml;
}
```

When i print or run the function as a  stand alone it gives me correct response. But when the webconnector sync happens it gives me the following error **Error message received from application via getLastError(): 3000: The given object ID "" in the field "list id" is invalid.**

When i am trying to debug in the QWClog file shows the following xml for custom add req

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <?qbxml version="13.0"?>
        <QBXML>
            <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
                <CustomerAddRq requestID="483">
                    <CustomerAdd>
                        <Name> </Name><BillAddress></BillAddress><Email></Email><Contact> </Contact></CustomerAdd>
                </CustomerAddRq>
            </QBXMLMsgsRq>
        </QBXML>
```

I see that here the name and billaddress fields are being empty. My question is that is the Drupal functions like user_load, commerce_order_load will work inside the mapping callback functions.

Comment: What's in the quickbooks_queue table? Do the queued up `ident` values look correct to you? Where's the part of your code that's actually queuing up stuff to be sent? Can you find the message that's throwing the error in the `quickbooks_log` SQL table?

Comment: My quickbook_queue table as two entry first one is CustomerAdd and second one is SalesReceiptAdd and ident value for both is 79 which i am hard coding(which is correct)  and i am queing my entries in the above soap end point after the  if (!QuickBooks_Utilities::initialized($dsn)) which is in above  reconnection_quickbooks_server function

Comment: Found my first mistake "As i am queuing inside the soap end point itself whenever Webconnector runs it is creating entries inside quickbook_queue table" now tried the queuing in a separate url call this solved my issue. Thanks Keith :D

Comment: I am trying to import an inventory item to qb now.. I am following https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/common/newosr/index.html ItemInventoryAdd xml format. In that it says to add an inventory we need to add IncomeAccount. My question is how to get an ListID of an income account? is the numbger which we are giving is same as ListID?

Comment: If you do an AccountQuery you'll get back the ListIDs. Or you can specify the FullName instead. Or you can specify the Account Number.